# Pointer on a struct containing a pointer : The array nomenclature works but not (ptr + 1). Why?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a hard time formulating my question, so I used onlinegdb to create an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct
{
    unsigned int GlobalHeader;
    unsigned char * Data;
}GLOBAL_DEVICE;

GLOBAL_DEVICE * GlobalDevice;

int main()
{
    GLOBAL_DEVICE GlobalTest[2];
    
    GlobalDevice = GlobalTest;
    
    char Buffer[] = {"ABCDEFG"};
    char TestChar;
    
    (GlobalDevice + 1)->Data = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    
    memcpy((GlobalDevice + 1)->Data,Buffer,8);
    
    //TestChar = (GlobalDevice + 1)->(Data + 1); <- This doesn't work. Error : expected identifier before '('
    TestChar = (GlobalDevice + 1)->Data[1]; // This works
    
    printf(&TestChar);
    
    return 0;
}
```

As described in the example above, why can I use (ptr+1) nomenclature on GlobalDevice pointer, but not on the Data pointer contained in the GlobalDevice pointed structure. I can use the array notation though for the Data pointer with no error.

My understanding is that the nomenclature array[i] is equal to *(array + i) and that works with GlobalDevice pointer.

So why can't I write

```
GlobalDevice[1]->Data[1]
```

using the (ptr + 1 nomenclature)

```
(GlobalDevice + 1)->(Data + 1)
```

Thanks,

Jean-Francois

edit: For other people reading this question, my misunderstanding came from the fact that I thought that array[i] was equal to (array+i). That is a mistake and array[i] is equal to *(array+i).

Comment: `(GlobalDevice + 1)` is not the same as `GlobalDevice[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((GlobalDevice + 1)->Data) + 1`, or even just `(GlobalDevice + 1)->Data + 1`.

`Data` isn't itself a pointer, it's a member name, and makes no sense as an expression by itself except on the right side of `.` or `->`.  In particular it makes no sense as an operand to `+`.

A correction: `array[i]` is equivalent, not to `array+i`, but to `*(array+i)`.  So the correct equivalent of `(GlobalDevice + 1)->Data[1]` is `*((GlobalDevice + 1)->Data + 1)`.

I think the `[]` syntax is clearer here anyhow, in both places. I'd write

```
TestChar = GlobalDevice[1].Data[1];
```

(By the way, `printf(&TestChar)` at the end won't work, because `TestChar` isn't followed in memory by a null character, so `&TestChar` isn't a string.  Instead write `putchar(TestChar);` or `printf("%c", TestChar);`.)

Comment: I agree that the array nomenclature is easier to write, but I am trying to understand the pointers in depth.

Your answer makes sense. I will close the question. Thank you.